# Informix data source name not found and no default driver specified error

Tags: asp.net, iis, informix

I have setup a Wallboard for our Cisco Call Center connecting to the ccx database and everything works fine when I run it through Visual Studio however when I publish it out to IIS and try to view the page I am getting an:

```
ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver
```

when it goes to access the dataSource.  In my searches all I can find is that I need to add the driver to my connections string which I have attempted to do but still no luck.  What am missing?

```
connectionString="Dsn=Wallboard-1;driver={INFORMIX 3.50 32 BIT};server=uccx1_uccx;host=xxxx;service=1504;protocol=onsoctcp;database=db_cra;uid=xxx;pwd=xxxx"
```

Comment: has the informix driver been *installed* on the web server?

Comment: Yes, it has. I have the data source configured through odbcad32.exe under the SysWOW64 directory and the driver is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! When running on a 64-bit environment you need to go into the app pool your site is running on through IIS an enable 32-Bit Applications so it can access the SysWOW64 folder. It couldn't find the driver because it couldn't find the odbc dsn.